# Meteor.js full text search

Tags: mongodb, search, text, full-text-search, meteor

how can I do full text search with Meteor.js?

For example if I search through message field in posts collection in mongo light.

I read about Spomet but I have no clear idea how to use it.

Also, simple full text search example with mongo would be good.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you read this? http://shiggyenterprises.wordpress.com/2013/09/28/developing-a-full-text-search-enabled-meteor-app/

Comment: Yes, I read it but I need it a bit more clear example.

Comment: you look into this solution? http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Fulltext_search

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like searching through the desired fields with a regular expression. I use such a solution by myself in a project, however the regular expression is unescaped.

Assume you have a session variable 'search' set to the desired query, then you could do something like this:

**search.js**

```
Template.search.results = function () {
  var query = Session.get('search');
  var find = {};

  if (!!query) {
    // FIXME: Runs unescaped as regex, absolutely not ok
    _.extend(find, { message: { $regex: query, $options: 'i' } });
  }

  var posts = Posts.find(find);
  return { posts: posts };
};
```

**search.html**

```
<template name="search">
  ...
  <!-- search results begin -->
  {{#each results.posts}}
  {{> postItem}}
  {{/each}}
  <!-- search results end -->
  ...
</template>
```

I got this example from the project [hmmm](https://github.com/schuel/hmmm) and implemented it by myself in my project [minutocash](http://minutocash.sinndrin.ch/), where you can test the search function (sign in with a pre defined user, to see the search form). A working implementation of the the above code example is visible on github.com/dandelo/minutocash/tree/master/client/views/offers/search (sorry, I can't post more than two links because I don't have enough reputation on Stack Overflow).

Comment: I need something more suited for large data sets.

Comment: Searching with case-insensitive regular expressions is most definitely a bad idea for performance and large data sets. MongoDB 2.4+ has [Text Indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/) which are a much saner option and include features like word stemming, field weighting, and result scoring.

Answer (score 1):

There is also another way to implement a solution with Meteor. It's [Search Source](https://github.com/meteorhacks/search-source).

It's a kind of **typeahead** but without the UI part. It exposes a reactive datasource where you can use it to build the UI with Blaze as you need.

- Here's a demo app: https://instant-search-demo.meteor.com/

Above app is an instant search app to search Meteor packages. How it can build with search source is documented in [this](https://meteorhacks.com/implementing-an-instant-search-solution-with-meteor.html) article

In brief this is how search source works:

#### In client, create a source

```
var options = {
  keepHistory: 1000 * 60 * 5,
  localSearch: true
};
var fields = ['packageName', 'description'];

PackageSearch = new SearchSource('packages', fields, options);
```

#### Then in the server define the search source

```
SearchSource.defineSource('packages', function(searchText, options) {
  var options = {sort: {isoScore: -1}, limit: 20};

  if(searchText) {
    var regExp = buildRegExp(searchText);
    var selector = {packageName: regExp, description: regExp};
    return Packages.find(selector, options).fetch();
  } else {
    return Packages.find({}, options).fetch();
  }
});

function buildRegExp(searchText) {
  // this is dumb implementation
  var parts = searchText.trim().split(' ');
  return new RegExp("(" + parts.join('|') + ")", "ig");
}
```

#### Now get the data source and render it

```
Template.searchResult.helpers({
  getPackages: function() {
    return PackageSearch.getData({
      transform: function(matchText, regExp) {
        return matchText.replace(regExp, "<b>$&</b>")
      },
      sort: {isoScore: -1}
    });
  }
});
```

#### Finally do the search

```
PackageSearch.search("the text to search");
```

You can learn more about how each of the above works with from the [documentation](https://github.com/meteorhacks/search-source).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the package itself. I tried to look in the docs for what `isoScore` does but could not find it. Is it something that is used internally? Is it used to give indicate the search weight-age?

Comment: I am actually trying to implement a search solution where I need to give varying importance to the geaospatial distance, the title, availability dates, etc. Is this possible with the package?